# Play GlobalSettings Override not working

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I've been using the onStart method for a while and it works no problem, but when I try to override onBadRequest, I get an error:

Here's the class:

```
import models.User;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.error_page;

import static play.mvc.Results.badRequest;


public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app){
        Logger.info("Application started!");
        // Check if the database is empty
        if(User.find.findRowCount()==0){
            Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("initial-data.yml"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application app){
        Logger.info("Application stopped!");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onBadRequest(String uri, String error) {
        Logger.info("Bad Request");
        return badRequest(error_page.render());
    }

}
```

The first two work no problem, but the third one causes the error.

[Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onBadRequest%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)'s the API entry:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the old API.

Here's the API for Play 2.1.1:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/GlobalSettings.html

- Called when an action has been found, but the request parsing has failed.

  ```
  Result onBadRequest(Http.RequestHeader request, java.lang.String error)
  ```
- Called when an exception occurred.

  ```
  Result onError(Http.RequestHeader request, java.lang.Throwable t)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@Override
public Result onError(Http.RequestHeader request, Throwable t){
    Logger.error("Error thrown: " + t.getMessage());
    return internalServerError(error_page.render());
}
```

[This](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/GlobalSettings.java) page was useful. I'm still confused why the API is wrong.

I hope this helps out somebody with a similar problem.